# Is $\overline {conv}(T(M))\subset T(\overline {conv}(M))$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $(E,\left \| . \right \| )$ be a Banach space
$T:E\rightarrow E$ is a continuous and bounded mapping.

Let $x_0\in E$, we define a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as follows:
$$x_{n+1}=T(x_n) \text{ for }n=0,1,...  \:\:$$

Let $M_n=\overline {conv}(\{x_n,x_{n+1},...\})$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$.

-**Did we have:** $\overline {conv}(T(M_n))\subset T(\overline {conv}(M_n))$?

-**If not do you have any counterexample in mind?**

*Thank you in advance.*

---

$\overline{conv}(A)$ is the closure of the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of $A$ .

Comment: Why do we have an order on the Banach space? also don't you want $M_n$ without that conv? (because you take another conv afterwards)

Comment: @Yanko  No we dont need an order here, I modified it. Unfortunately i have to deal with that conv!

Answer (score 1):

If $||T||<1$ then the sequence $x_n $ tends to $0$ since $$||x_n ||\leq ||T||^{n -1} ||x_1||$$ hence the set $M_n $ is compact and convex and therefore $\overline{\mbox{conv} }(M_n )=M_n .$ The set $T(M_n )=T(\overline{\mbox{conv} }(M_n )) $ is closed and convex since it is compact and convex therefore $$\overline{\mbox{conv} } T(M_n ) =T(M_n )=T(\overline{\mbox{conv} }(M_n )).$$
If $||T|\geq 1$ the we can cosider a operator $$T_1 =\frac{1}{||T|| +1 }T$$